# Font changes (but shouldn't) when switching to other split subwindow in emacs

Tags: emacs, fonts, emacs24

In .emacs, I've set a larger font for Kanji, but want to retain the smaller font for Hiragana and Katakana:

```
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" 'han "Sazanami Gothic:size=18")
(set-fontset-font "fontset-default" '(#x3000 . #x30ff) "Sans")
```

That works when loading files etc.

When I use a horizontally split window, and switch to other subwindow, the font of the Hiragana in the subwindow I'm leaving sometimes changes to the large font. Is that because the unicode ranges overlap, and the order of the definitions is not respected? How should I correctly specify the ranges, i.e. can I exclude the range from 'han, or do I need to hunt down the definition of 'han and correct the ranges manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question: I replaced the 'han (script name symbol) with cons'd ranges

```
'(#x3400 . #x4dff) '(#x4e00 . #x9fff) '(#x20000 . #x2bfff)
```

to the CJK unicode blocks in 3 different calls. That works.

Apparently overlapping font definitions using script name symbols and ranges are evaluated somewhat nondeterministically, so I got sometimes one and sometimes the other.

Answer (score 0):

In general, fonts such as buffer background and buffer foreground are changed globally -- either on a per frame basis or all frames -- *not* on a per buffer or per window basis.  The following are two examples of how to affect only one buffer:

```lisp
(defun buffer-background-red ()
(interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face `(:background "red"))
  (buffer-face-mode 1))

(defun zoom ()
(interactive)
  (setq buffer-face-mode-face `(:height 375))
  (buffer-face-mode 1))
```

Comment: I don't want to affect only one buffer. What I want is to display the Kanji in one particular font and size, and the Hiragana/Katagana (which are apparently included in the 'han constant) with the normal size. This works with the two lines given above. BUT, sometimes the Hiragana/Katakana font changes by itself when switching windows, even though I don't want it to. I don't understand why, and this is what I want to AVOID.

Comment: This sounds like it might be a bug, but I'm no authority on fontsets and such.  If you don't get a useful answer here shortly, consider filing an Emacs bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.  Emacs developers will be able to tell you whether this is a bug.  And if not, they might mention a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround (untested), you might try using font-lock to apply a different *face* to the chars in question (assuming you can easily target them for font-lock using either a regexp or a function). The face can specify the character size.